# JS/jQuery - Try to achieve show a div on and off use mouseenter() mouseleave() so not to get repeated animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, mouseenter, mouseleave

So here's my code:

```
   var timeouts = {};
    $('#nav ul > li').mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout(timeouts['menu']);
        $(this).find('div.dropdown').stop(true).slideDown(200);
    });
    $('#nav ul > li').mouseleave(function() {
        timeouts['menu'] = setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).find('div.dropdown').stop(true).slideUp(200);
        }, 1000)
    });
```

This doesn't seem to be working. Any idea?
Is there any other way to achieve my goal? The code now works when I hover my mouse over but the div will not slide up when my mouse leaves.

Comment: Is your list generated dynamically ?

Comment: No, it's not. The code works fine if i remove setTimeouts.

Comment: clear the code inside it and pust just some alert inside mouseenter and mouseleave function and see if its works

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your anonymous function, `this` is probably not defined as a HTML element.

Put `this` in the proper scope:

```
var timeouts = {'menu': false};

$('#nav ul > li').hover(function() {
    if (timeouts['menu'] !== false) {
      clearTimeout(timeouts['menu']);
    }

    $(this).find('div.dropdown').stop(true).slideDown(200);
}, function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    timeouts['menu'] = setTimeout(function() {
        $this.find('div.dropdown').stop(true).slideUp(200);
    }, 1000)
});
```

Also, you're probably going to get an error if you try to call `timeouts['menu']` without it being defined first. I'd set it to a default value and then check if it exists before using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [hoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) plugin or have a look at some of the solutions here: [jQuery if mouse is over for 2 sec. begin animation or don't animate at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7869019/jquery-if-mouse-is-over-for-2-sec-begin-animation-or-dont-animate-at-all)